# What is the status of npm "isolated mode" for monorepos?

Tags: npm, monorepo

As it currently stands (March 2023), there is not very much information available when you search "npm isolated mode". The initial discussion began in [this github PR](https://github.com/npm/rfcs/pull/436?ref=jonathan-creamer), which evolved into the [official RFC](https://github.com/npm/rfcs/blob/main/accepted/0042-isolated-mode.md). However, there is no indication as to the roadmap or planned release of this feature.

**Question:** What is the status of isolated mode in npm?

**Motivation:** To help the community keep an eye on a critical feature about which NPM team has gone silent.

**UPDATES (as I find them):**

- In May 2022, one of the npm maintainers said that isolated mode was ["under way"](https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/4959#issuecomment-1142751509).
- There is a [branch for isolated mode](https://github.com/npm/cli/tree/vibailly/isolated-mode) in the npm repo, but it has not been updated since August 2022.

Comment: You can use it by setting `install-strategy=linked` in `.npmrc`. You can check the isolated-mode unit tests in `arborist`: https://github.com/npm/cli/blob/latest/workspaces/arborist/test/isolated-mode.js#L247. Although it is called `isolated-mode`, the flag is `linked`.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to the comment by `@mpsq` above, this feature has been available in npm since January 2023 under the `--install-strategy=linked` setting. Here are the notes:

- Only available in npm v9 or greater.
- Read the docs for npm [`-install-strategy`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/commands/npm-install#install-strategy)
- The "linked" strategy is still experimental as of February 2024.